# Swift - Call a function when button is pressed - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, swift2, unrecognized-selector

I'm programmatically adding some buttons to my toolbar using swift. I've seen how to add an action to a button and I think I'm doing it correctly, but obviously I'm not because I keep getting "unrecognized selector sent to instance" when I press the button. What am I doing wrong?

Here's how I'm adding the buttons to the toolbar:

```
func addButtonsToToolbar(view: UIView?)
{
    let userTrackingArrow = MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem(mapView: self.mapView)
    let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let refresh: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Refresh, target: view, action: "refreshbuttonTapped:")

    var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
    items.append(userTrackingArrow)
    items.append(flexSpace)
    items.append(refresh)

    self.toolBar.items = items
}
```

This is the function I want called with the "refresh" button is pressed, but it's not being called. Instead I get "unrecognized selector sent to instance".

```
func refreshbuttonTapped(sender: AnyObject!)
{
    print("Button tapped")
}
```

Comment: Where is `func refreshbuttonTapped(sender: AnyObject!)`? Same class with `func addButtonsToToolbar(view: UIView?)`? And what is `(view: UIView?)`?

Comment: Yes it's defined in the same class as addButtonsToToolbar and view is self.mapView

Comment: If you post the error from the console it would help. As mentioned it is probably looking for refreshbuttonTapped on the wrong view. You might want self which will be your view controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change target of refresh button:

```
let refresh: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Refresh, target: view, action: "refreshbuttonTapped:")
```

to:

```
let refresh: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Refresh, target: self, action: "refreshbuttonTapped:")
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `refreshbuttonTapped()` must be implemented in the `target` class, that's the `view` passed as parameter in `addButtonsToToolbar()`